# Can I install Ubuntu on a MacMIni G4?

Tags: installation, mac

Can I install Ubuntu on a MacMini machine? It has a G4 Processor, not intel, it's a great machine and unfortunately it is being outdated, is there any hope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical has not officially supported these older PowerPC based machines for quite a while.  This was left to the community to support.

There is not currently a Natty version to try - the latest stable release is Maverick.

[Power PC Wiki Page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Is%20Ubuntu%20supported%20on%20PowerPC?)

[Power PC Downloads](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads)

[Apple Users Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=328)

However - things look promising for the upcoming LTS (12.04) - in the [daily-builds](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) there is a PowerPC ISO.